# C++ Is there a way to work around circular dependency?

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

Now I know that in C++ everything has to be declared before it can be used. But what if I have two functions that reference each other?
For example:

```
void func1() {
  func2();
}

void func2() {
  func1();
}
```

Is it completely impossible to do this?

Comment: The title uses the phrase 'forward declaration', but the question seems to be predicated on ignorance of what a forward declaration actually is. A forward declaration of a function, also called a function prototype, is a declaration which does not define the function. Your code does not include any forward declarations. Adding one is how you make the code compile.

Comment: So then if this problem is not called forward declaration, then what is it called? I apologise for my ignorance; C++ isn't my main language and I don't encounter such problems with Lua

Comment: The problem is called a circular dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A forward declaration is exactly what you want:

```
void func2(); // forward declare func2

void func1() {
  func2();
}

void func2() {
  func1();
}
```

The first `void func2();` is called a forward declaration.  You promise that you will define it according to this prototype eventually.

Answer (score 3):

You need to forward declare `func2()` to be able to use it in `func1()`:

```
void func2();

void func1() {
  func2();
}

void func2() {
  func1();
}
```

Now at the point where `func1()` references `func2()`, `func2()` has been declared, and at the point where `func2()` references `func1()`, `func1()` will have been declared.

However, calling either one of the two functions will cause an infinite loop, which will result in a stack overflow.

Comment: Not an infinite loop unless you have infinite memory. More likely a stack overflow.

Comment: @RPGillespie The compiler could implement tail recursion, which could make it an infinite loop. In any case, technically the behavior of the code shown is undefined.

Comment: I noticed the infinite loop the functions would create.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply place one function inside the other, then expressed as a (usually `static`) member function of a class, or as a lambda.

This assuming that the top-level calls from elsewhere are always to one of the functions.

Another possibility, with both functions available to the top-level calling code, is to place both functions as (most naturally `static`) members of a class, where they can be defined inline.

But I think it's more clean to just use the forward declaration.

There isn't really any good reason to avoid it, so a workaround like one of those mentioned above would just make other programmers waste some time scratching their heads – what on Earth is this *for*?

---

Amendment: example of the class scope approach:

```
struct Recursive
{
    static void func1() { if( some_condition ) { func2(); } }
    static void func2() { if( some_condition ) { func1(); } }
};
```

Example of the nested functions approach:

```
void func1()
{
    const auto func2 = []{ if( some_condition ){ func1(); } }
    if( some_condition ) { func2(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that snippet of code impossible without some sort of forward declaration? Yes. Think about it, when the compiler gets here:

```
void func1() {
  func2();
}
```

He has never seen `func2` before, and therefore can't compile it.

Most people create a `.h` file that contains function declarations so you can avoid this type of thing. For example,

### `foo.h`

```
void func1();
void func2();
```

### `foo.c`

```
#include "foo.h"

void func1() {
  func2();
}

void func2() {
  func1();
}
```

Comment: The reasoning here doesn't hold water.

Comment: As an example, in a class with these functions as inline function definitions the compiler has not seen `func2` when it's used in `func1` (assuming `func1` is defined first). One way to *understand* it is to think in terms of transformed source code where the definitions are moved to after the class. But the compiler doesn't have to do that, and there is nothing technical that would stop it for doing the same (backpatching, transform, whatever) for functions defined at namespace scope -- if the language had allowed it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I was just trying to put it in a way OP could understand. At the global namespace level, C/C++ compilers are very simple and procedural. You can't reference a type or call a function unless the compiler has somehow been made aware of it first.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible with member functions. For example:

```
class A {
  void func1() {
    func2();
  }
  void func2() {
    func1();
  }
};
```

It can be more problematic if you need two classes to know about each other but does that answer your question?

Edit: You don't need the member function declarations before their definitions.

Comment: Defining the functions after the class gives the impression that that's necessary. It isn't.

Comment: Ah yes that is the important point; using member functions you can declare these in any order, the compiler will take care of the rest.

This is more concise:

    class A {
      void func1() { func2(); }
      void func2() { func1(); }
    };

Comment: This looks like Java... :(

Answer (score 0):

You should accept one of the other answers because that's how the language C++ works and there's nothing to do about it, if your concern is that writing lots of forwards is a pain, you should note that several frameworks already provide headers just for the sake of forward declaring stuff so that users don't have too.

This is for convenience when there's really a lot of stuff that is forward declared or there's stuff that need to be declared correctly (in example templates, aliases and also I saw some macro trickery once in a while).

Also generally you have to put declarations and definitions in different files to avoid recompiling where possible and generally to make the project more clear and manageable.

**Functions.hpp**

```
void func();
void func2();
```

**Functions.cpp**

```
#include "Functions.hpp"

void func(){
    func2();
}

void func2(){
    func();
}
```

user code:
**main.cpp**

```
#include "Functions.hpp"

int main(){
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

Also note that you have some confusion about "Declaration" and "Forward Declaration".

Actually when you put a function signature in your code your are **Declaring** it:

```
int function3(); // function declared
```

**Forward declaration** is about telling a class exists without telling anything more about its signature:

```
class myclass;  //forward declaration

//possible declarations using "myclass" forward declaration
int function4(myclass & ref);
int function5(myclass * ref);
```

Forward declaration is used to keep headers simple and reducing compile time (a lot in certain cases) by moving unneeded details to implementation (.cpp) files.

Comment: [No need for a pointer or reference.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aeeadf23b8df62db)

Comment: for function parameters and return type yes, but cannot have class members without full declaration.

Comment: Of course, but your list of possible declarations makes it seem like you can't for function parameters.